# How to launch the terminal in gnome?

Tags: gnome

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 Desktop 32 bit, and I can't find any icon or menu to launch the terminal. Is something wrong? How can I access the terminal?

Comment: Hi black and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is there a reason you aren't using Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the search icon on the launcher.  Type term.  At least one should be listed.  You can launch it from there and then pin it (lock it) to the launchbar.

If it's not there, you can install it thusly:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Alternately, if the terminal software is installed,

```
<ctrl><alt> t
```

will launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[Here are some other options](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22283/four-ways-to-get-instant-access-to-a-terminal-in-linux/)